# Need to get current boundaries of the view in longitude and latitude from current zooming and panning values in OSM maps

Tags: c#, google-maps, maps, openstreetmap, osmdroid

In OSM, i need to know longitude and latitude of my four corners of current area as in this image in OSM.

[OSM Map current Area Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBRHF.png)

By the below code I got the center X and Y value of the control

var centerX = TileLayer.ControlSize.Width / 2;

var centerY = TileLayer.ControlSize.Height / 2;

By using the below method I converted the center pixel value to latitude and 
  longitude.

```
private PointF GetPanChangedArguments(double pointX, double pointY)
{
PointF pointXY = new PointF();

foreach (var tile in TileLayer.Tiles)
{
if (tile.ImageBounds != null && tile.ImageBounds.Contains((int)pointX, (int)pointY))
{
  var actualXPoint = (pointX - tile.ImageBounds.Left);
  var actualYPoint = (pointY - tile.ImageBounds.Top);
  var tileSize3 = ((1 << (TileLayer.Scale - tile.Scale)) * 256);
 tileSize3 = (int)(tileSize3 * SfMaps.DENSITY);
 var point = TileLayer.PointToLatLon(actualXPoint + tile.X * tileSize3, actualYPoint + tile.Y * tileSize3, TileLayer.Scale);
  pointXY = new PointF(point.X, point.Y);
  break;
   }
 }

  return pointXY;
}
```

Now I need top left corner latitude and longitude, I used to pass the 0,0 in this method, but the image bounds are not updated for the scale value 1.1,1,2..etc, the bounds value is updated only for scale value 2.
how to update the current bounds of the tiles and how to get the coordinates of the top left corner. Or is any other way to find the `topleftcorner` coordinate of OSM

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Where exaclty are you struggling? Would you share your attempts with us?

Comment: See following webpage : https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/1069/how-to-calculate-the-size-of-a-map-tile-on-the-ground